# How to protect goods in a shipping container?

Tags: moving

When shipping goods, including computer hardware, books, clothes and tableware, across the globe (crossing the equator) in a container it seems natural that heat, humidity and physical impact would be the main issues. But the details are not so obvious:

1. What magnitude are they, for example, how high does the temperature actually go, and how many newtons of (sustained/impact) force can be expected?
2. Are any unusual measures (other than simply stacking in cardboard boxes) necessary to protect the goods adequately?
3. Are there any other factors which are important? For example, are containers regularly dropped from any height? Are they ever turned on their side? Do the contents have to be packed so that inspectors can get to every single thing easily? Are there pests? Etc.

Comment: There are various devices that can be placed on and in shipping containers to verify that certain conditions have been maintained. Some indicate maximum and minimum temperatures while others for orientation and impact. There are many varieties of them. They can be certified and insurance companies accept them as evidence of treatment. While you might not be able to protect your value during shipment, insurance may be able to partially compensate you for subsequent losses if they do occur.

Answer (score 2):

Containers on ships are single orientation objects, they aren't dropped unless by accident, but temperatures can exceed 65°C/150F inside a container given the right conditions/destination, I would suggest excessive bubble wrap and many boxes with less in them than maximizing each box's potential storing ability.
Got a nice vase?  It gets it's own box.  Pack your stuff so that if your whole pile of boxes got knocked over that nothing would break...more boxes with less in them and LOTS of bubble wrap, but get the new kind with long cells rather than little bubbles.  also get a case of rolls of tape for the bubble wrap and boxes.  think about silicon packets for things that need to stay dry.